What's the point of doing minimalistic edits on really old posts, followed by closing them?
Today I suddenly got a bunch of notifications about an old question of mine being edited and closed. Specifically this question:
PHP check if array value is unique
I don't mind the question being closed. If it's a duplicate, it's a duplicate. Simple as that. But I find it really odd that a higher reputation user went out of their way to do very minimalistic edits on every single answer, followed by closing the nearly 7 year old question itself as a duplicate. What's the point of it?
I mean, if you close a question, it'll eventually be gone as far as I know. Any reputations and other data linked to it will be removed, unless the system decides that removing the question would have too much of an impact on everyone involved. So why bother doing all those really small edits if you gonna close the question anyway?

Closing a question as a duplicate won't cause it to disappear etc. Only deleting it will. Otherwise it operates as a "signpost" to the linked "master" duplicate target.

if you close a question, it'll eventually be gone as far as I know. No, only closed question with a  < 0 score and no positive/accepted answer will roomba: https://stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions

The person that edited the question is not the one that closed the question.

@MisterMiyagi True. They marked it as duplicate and someone with an arrays badge confirmed it. But like I said, the closure itself was not my reason for asking. I personally don't really agree with it, but I can see why others might. I just found it really odd to see all those small edits and thought closed questions were eventually purged, that's all.

So a thorough [edit] of this question is really needed to question the minimal edits and remove any references to closure and other extraneous issues. Essentially everything after the word "answer" in para 2 (and the title needs review too!).

@Paulie_D That wouldn't make much sense. Edits, no matter how small, as long as they improve a post, are fine to do as far as I know. I wouldn't ask about that, even if I thought it was a bit strange. It was my understanding that closed questions with a small impact on the community would eventually be removed. If that was true, the edits wouldn't made any sense. But as you've explained, it's not true. I can edit the question, but it would just end in "it's odd someone is doing minimalistic edits".

I’m voting to close this question myself because it's based on a misunderstanding of how Stack Overflow works.

One user modified it, forcing it on the front page, resulting in somebody with a gold tag closing it. All this is in the history of the question.  "They marked it as duplicate." - No, The user who edited your question did not mark it as duplicate. A lack of basic understanding of the edit system and the fact that the question is not even grounded in reality forced me to downvote this meta-question.

First of all you seem have the timeline wrong:



Peter Mortensen is, despite being a regular user, titled by the community as our resident Editor-In-Chief. All posts are subject to his (or any user really) improvements, some small, some large, the end result is always better. Peter only edited, he didn't vote (up/down, close).
Editing a question (and/or any of its answers) "bumps" a question. This leads to the question being send to the top of the active tab for the tags they carry: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?tab=Active
That is where Goldbadge holder mickmackusa comes in. He is known for patrolling the PHP tag and has a wide arsenal of canonical duplicates for common questions in the PHP tag. Two hours after Peter bumped the question, mickmackusa casted a single duplicate close vote, and due to his gold badge in both arrays and php the question was closed instantly.
You say in your question:

if you close a question, it'll eventually be gone as far as I know.

That is not correct. There are complex rules that governs when a question gets deleted automatically. Only closed questions with a negative score and no positive and/or accepted answer will roomba: https://stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions

So why bother doing all those really small edits if you gonna close the question anyway?

The question (and its answers) can now serve as so called sign-posts. Visitors that arrive via a Google search will find the closed question that points them  to the best canonical we have with all knowledge in one place. Duplicates act as SEO.
See also Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?

I am discovering and understanding new depths of SO.
